# How to create Custom Page Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I share with you how to create a custom page PHP in Prestashop 1.7

*I am showing in this example the brands, but you can show other sql queries, etc*

1° Create the controller *BrandsJatController.php* to /override/controllers/front/

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Class BrandsJatController
 * @author      Jatniel Guzmán
 * @copyright   2020 Jatniel Guzmán
 * @license     MIT License
 * @link        https://jatnielguzman.com
 * @link        https://twitter.com/jatnieldev
 */

class BrandsJatController extends FrontController
{

    public $php_self = 'brands';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {

        $brands = $this->getBrands();
        
        $this->context->smarty->assign('lorem', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis lacinia massa. 
        Fusce ante purus, aliquet eget porttitor ut, sodales in risus. Nunc gravida ipsum id gravida pretium.');
        
        $this->context->smarty->assign('dev', 'Jatniel Guzmán');
        
        $this->context->smarty->assign($brands);

        parent::initContent();

        // themes/mytheme/templates/brandsjat.tpl
        $this->setTemplate('brandsjat.tpl'); 
    }

    public function getBrands(){

        $brands = Manufacturer::getManufacturers(false, (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);

        foreach ($brands as &$brand) {

            $brand['image'] = $this->context->language->iso_code.'-default';

            $brand['link'] = $this->context->link->getManufacturerLink($brand['id_manufacturer']);

            $fileExist = file_exists(
                _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_ . $brand['id_manufacturer'] . '-' .
                ImageType::getFormattedName('medium').'.jpg'
            );

            if ($fileExist) {
                $brand['image'] = $brand['id_manufacturer'];
            }
        }

        return  array(
            'brands' => $brands,
            'page_link' => $this->context->link->getPageLink('manufacturer'),
            'text_list_nb' => Configuration::get('BRAND_DISPLAY_TEXT_NB'),
            'brand_display_type' => Configuration::get('BRAND_DISPLAY_TYPE'),
            'display_link_brand' => Configuration::get('PS_DISPLAY_SUPPLIERS'),
        );
    }

}
```

2° Create the file *brandsjat.tpl* to /themes/mytheme/templates/

```
{**
 * Custom Page Brands Prestashop 1.7
 *
 * @package     Class BrandsJatController
 * @author      Jatniel Guzmán
 * @copyright   2020 Jatniel Guzmán
 * @license     MIT License
 * @link        https://jatnielguzman.com
 * @link        https://twitter.com/jatnieldev
*}

{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='page_header_container'}{/block}

{block name='page_title'}
<span class="sitemap-title">{l s='Nos Marques' d='Shop.Theme'}</span>
{/block}

{block name='page_content'}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">NOS MARQUES</h1>
            <p class="h4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis lacinia massa. Fusce ante
                purus, aliquet eget porttitor ut, sodales in risus. Nunc gravida ipsum id gravida pretium. Praesent
                sodales viverra velit, interdum laoreet ex tempus a. In lacus est, lacinia ac vehicula in, posuere
                ac sapien. Morbi vel luctus purus, in lobortis erat.</p>
            <div class="row">

                {foreach from=$brands item=brand}

                {* BOX BRAND *}

                <div class="col-md-5 mt-md-5 border border-dark mx-auto l-3">

                    <div class="float-left w-50">
                        <img src="{$urls.img_manu_url}{$brand.image}.jpg" class="img-fluid w-75 my-5">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="float-right w-50">
                        <h2 class="text-break text-lg-center">{$brand.name}</h2>
                        <p> 
                            {if !empty($brand.short_description)}
                                {$brand.short_description|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:266:'...'}
                            {else}
                                {$lorem}
                            {/if}
                        </p>
                        <a href="{$brand.link}" class="">Voir tous les produits</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                {* END BOX BRAND *}

                {/foreach}

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/block}
```

3° In the back office -> Shop parameters -> Traffic & SEO, and in the "+" Add anew page.

- Page name, select -> brands.
- Rewritten URL, we write the url -> example our-brands

verify the url: https://www.myshop-ps.com/our-brands

The code is available from [github.com/jatniel/custom_page_prestashop](https://github.com/jatniel/custom_page_prestashop).

Best regards,

Jatniel

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: no questions, just share how to make a custom page in prestashop

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I have a 404 error. I downloaded files from github, placed them in the right directories, added my custom URL, cleared cache and class_index.php... Nothing works :(

Comment: Hi @Neoweiter 
What version of prestashop do you use?
Have you checked the logs? Prestashop debug mode activated, what error does it show?

Comment: Hi @Jatniel, thanks for your quick answer. I'm on PS 1.7.8.0, and debug does not show real error, only notices. Regarding the 404 error, I mean I have the "Page not found" from prestashop. Not a browser 404

Comment: Found the solution, it was a server configuration to change from Nginx to Apache. Works like a charm now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Neoweiter, don't forget to give a point score or a star if you like!! ;-)